# How to add multiple UIViews in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a UIView that draws a pie chart and I would like to put 3 or maybe 4 charts in a UIScrollView programatically. How can I do that?

my h file is like this

```
@class PieChart;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

and m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


[scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
    scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;     
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;


         PieChart *chart = [[PieChart alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [chart setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)];

    [scrollView addSubview:chart];

}
```

Comment: ahh sorry i am new i didnt know that.. will do that soon.. cheers

Comment: It's probably unrelated, but this is a little confusing because you have an `IBOutlet` for `m_piechart` (which you then have a `@property` for, for which you fail to specify the `IBOutlet` and you don't specify as `weak` ... also if you do it in IB, make sure to specify the `PieChart` as the view's class) and then you don't use it, but rather create it programmatically. You should do one or the other (Interface Builder or programmatically), but not both.

Comment: Well yes u are right.. i wanted to do that manually then later on I decided to do it programatically.. that's why IBOutlet remains there..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to add subview to the view you need to use `[view addSubview:subview]`. This is common practice. 
Read about frames and bounds (coordinate systems for view and sub views):

- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Coordinates/Coordinates.html

As I understand you have a problem due to content size of scroll view. Read more here:

- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/Introduction/Introduction.html

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can just **add** it with:

```
[scrollView addSubview:singleView];
```

Comment: I tried that using `PieChart *chart = [[PieChart alloc]init]; [scrollView addSubview:chart];` but no luck

Comment: try: [chart setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)]; It doesnt have a frame yet. This will set the chart on coordinate (100,100) with a size of 200x200

Comment: Yep, or `initWithFrame` instead of `init` and then `setFrame`

Comment: Yep, I'd also suggest specifying the background color of the chart itself, too, to see if its basic view shows up. And thanks for the code, but we probably need the initialization code for the `PieChart` itself, not the view controller's.

Answer (score 0):

You add multiple subviews to a `UIScrollView` just like you add a single subview; with `addSubview:`. What problems are you running into?

Comment: What I am doing is `PieChart *chart = [[PieChart alloc]init];`
  `[scrollView addSubview:chart];` and that fails

Comment: If you set the frames for your three or four pie charts within the larger scrollview, you should be fine. Note, you don't have to restrict your frames to the dimensions of the screen, but rather to the size of the scrollview's [`contentSize`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentSize), which you'll adjust to fit all of your charts.

Comment: my uiview class for drawing piechart.. i get no error as well as no chart

Comment: Sounds like it's just a basic problem in your `PieChart`. I'd check the `viewDidLoad` for it, make sure your `frame` settings are right, etc. If that's not working, you might want to edit your question to include some of the relevant `PieChart` code (notably `viewDidLoad` and whatever `init` methods you use), and we can probably advise more. We can't offer any suggestions in the absence of code.

Comment: Another thing to try: set different `backgroundColor` properties for your `PieChart` and `UIScrollView` objects to see where they appear.

Comment: If you set a background color for your `PieChart`, where does it appear? Do you see the scrollView's background color? How about a screenshot?

Comment: If it appears property, then it sounds like your problem lies elsewhere, as @RobertRyan suggested.